# How to use service container correcly?

Tags: 8, dependency-injection

I want to use service container inside my class so I have this this:

```
class SomeController extends ControllerBase {

  protected $entityTypeManager;
  protected $requestStack;

  public function __construct(EntityTypeManagerInterface $entityTypeManager,RequestStack $requestStack){
    $this->entityTypeManager = $entityTypeManager;
    $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
   }

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('entity_type.manager'),
      $container->get('request_stack'),
    );
  }

  public function content() {
    $testEntityTypeManager = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node')->getQuery();
    $testRequest = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
    //do something with these...
  }

}
```

What I wanted to do here is create a container for EntityTypeManager and RequestStack. Now phpStorm is giving me a warning regarding `public static function create(ContainerInterface $container)` and it says `Method call uses 2 parameters, but method signature uses 1 parameters` and I can't use it in my method `content()`.

$testEntityTypeManager and $testRequest are just examples with which I would do something else but even now it doesn't work and phpStorm tells me getCurrentRequest().

Sure I can use them statically but that is not what I'm trying to achieve here. Any push in right direction is appreciated!

Comment: The method name should be `__construct` and not `__constructor`

Comment: @kevin Thanks! PhpStorm still showing same warning.

Comment: You have a MYMODULE.services.yml?

Comment: @leymannx No I don't. I have MYMODULE.services but not  MYMODULE.services.yml 
Don't I inherit these services from core.services.yml? Or do I still have to make a reference to them?

Comment: A controller receives the request as argument content(Request $request) and $entityTypeManager is already provided through the base class. It's unclear what you are trying to achieve, but if you want to have a clean controller class with proper DI then don't extend ControllerBase, only implement ContainerInjectionInterface.

Comment: @4k4 Okey I'll try to do that then. Not that experienced with dependency injection that's why I asked for help. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: OK, then don't start with this container factory thing, you rarely need this. Use the base class as it is or build a service and inject via mymodule.services.yml, which you can use as controller, too, see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/structure-of-routes

Answer (score 0):

The error:

> `Method call uses 2 parameters, but method signature uses 1`

Your create() method is defined to only receive a single argument, `$container`. This must be a debugger in PHPStorm giving you this output, because what it is saying is that the code calling SomeController::create() is passing two arguments. So the second is getting lost. Your problem is likely stemming from that, and probably means one of two things:

1. The code calling the create() function is mistakenly passing a second value, or
2. Your create() function needs to be re-defined to catch the second argument, and do something with it.

[ControllerBase::create](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Controller%21ControllerBase.php/function/ControllerBase%3A%3Acreate/8.7.x) only expects a single argument, `$container`, and since your function defines that, I'd guess the more likely culprit is the calling function passing an unnecessary argument (#1 above). However, if the passed variable is necessary for some reason, SomeController::create() can be redefined to catch an optional argument:

```
public function create(ContainerInteface $container, $additional_param1 = NULL) {
  if (is_null($additional_param1)) {
    throw new \Exception('$additional_param_1 is required');
  }

  // Continue as normal.

}
```

Comment: It's also possible this persons code had no `use` statements. Since they are extending `ControllerBase`, I am not sure how the above scenario could happen unless there is custom code not mentioned overriding some core definition.

Comment: Good addition. I’ll update my reply

Comment: @Jaypan Thanks! This works. I already had correct use statements.

Comment: If my answer fixed your problem, please mark it as the correct answer. Thank you.